1950s or 60s black-and-white show where aliens took over an old TV set
Black-and-white, early 1960s or late 50s. Old box TV on 4-legged wire stand moves by itself.  It was rolling down the street and people were hiding.

Did it look like stop motion?

If someone posts the correct answer (not certain that mine is), you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. Incorrect answers are an excellent opportunity to [edit] more detail in.

Is it possible that you're referring to The Twonky as per this unaccepted answer?

After seeing his wife (Janet Warren) off on her trip, Kerry West (Hans Conried), a philosophy teacher at a small-town college goes inside his home to contemplate his new purchase: a television set. Sitting down in his office, he places a cigarette in his mouth and is about to light it when a solid beam of light shoots from the television screen, lighting it for him. Absentmindedly unaware of what has taken place, it is only when the television subsequently lights his pipe that West realizes that his television is behaving abnormally.
West soon discovers that the television can walk and perform a variety of functions, including dishwashing, vacuuming, and card-playing. When the television deliveryman (Edwin Max) returns to settle the bill, the television materializes copies of a five-dollar bill in order to provide payment. Yet the television soon exhibits other, more controlling traits, permitting West only a single cup of coffee and breaking West’s classical music records in favor of military marches to which it dances. After West demonstrates the television to his friend Coach Trout (Billy Lynn), the coach declares the television set to be a “twonky”, the word he used as a child to label the inexplicable.

Film Online



Not quite matching, it's implied to be from humans in the future, not from aliens (the short story by the same name that this film is based on is more explicit about it being built by someone caught in a "temporal snag", although the characters briefly speculate about Martians).
